# How to push data from Amazon Connect (e.g. Historical Metrics) to Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-redshift, amazon-connect

Is there any API i can use or write a lambda function! (**GetMetricData**)
what steps to follow?
What i am willing to do is push the Amazon Connect Data (like Historical reports) to redshift.
What could be the possible scenarios to accomplish this? Data can be pushed on regular intervals. in other words i want to retrieve data of amazon connect instance in redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions Architects at AWS created an opinionated solution for this a few years ago, which is available via a Quick Start (CloudFormation template) [here](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/connect/data-streaming/). It may not be fully up to date, as it was created some time ago, but it will likely give you a functional model to follow and the example lambda code you would need to build a solution that works for you.

Comment: Thank you. i have found another way:
- As we can schedule amazon connect historical reports and reports will be pushed to s3 automatically
- Then we can schedule a Copy query in redshift that will pull the data from s3 bucket file and dump it in redshift table.

Comment: i don't want to use Kinesis FireHose at all. so trying to get another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy Agent1 from 's3://my-bucket/connect/oblab2/Reports/Historical Metrics Report (1).csv'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::my-rule:role/RedshiftRoleForS3'
csv
null as '\000'
IGNOREHEADER 1;
```

I am using this (above) to pull the data from s3 to redshift table. its working fine but there is one problem as when data is pulled/copied very first time it inserted into table but when the data get updated in s3 bucket file and we run the same query what it does is add the whole new rows of data instead of overwriting the already created rows.

Comment: If this solves your problem, good for you. About the problem your experiencing, if you need help with it it's best to ask a separate question